# how to filter only a specific key value from an array of dictionaries using NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c

```
NSArray *details = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name",@"age",@"gender",nil];
NSArray *ray1  = @[@"ray",@"23",@"male"];
NSArray *steve1  = @[@"steve",@"23",@"male"];
NSDictionary *ray = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:ray1 forKeys:details];
NSDictionary *steve = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:steve1 forKeys:details];
NSArray *register = @[ray,steve];
```

i need to filter only the values of key using NSPredicate

Comment: first of all, you cant use `register` as a variable name, it is a keyword!!!

Comment: Can you explain what you want? only values in array without keys? Like, {ray,23,male}. or you want predicate to work just like objectForKey: ?

Comment: thank u for the response Anoop Vaidya....i found the answer for it.

Comment: i just need to print the values of specific key like(ray,steve)

Comment: NSPredicate *pr = [NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES];
    NSArray *ar = [[reg valueForKey:@"name"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pr];
    NSLog(@"%@",ar);

Answer (score 1):

this prints the values of the key "name" of all the dictionaries

```
NSArray *details = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name",@"age",@"gender",nil];
NSArray *ray1  = @[@"ray",@"23",@"male"];
NSArray *steve1  = @[@"steve",@"23",@"male"];
NSDictionary *ray = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:ray1 forKeys:details];
NSDictionary *steve = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:steve1 forKeys:details];
NSArray *reg = @[ray,steve];
NSPredicate *pr = [NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES];
NSArray *ar = [[reg valueForKey:@"name"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pr];
NSLog(@"%@",ar);
```